# Laravel: работа с двумя базами

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Возникла потребность помимо основной базы подключаться еще к внешней, которая находится на другом сервере. Подскажите плз как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот решение:

1. Зайти в файл config/database.php и добавить там новое соединение в массив:

   ```
   'mysql2' => [
           'driver'    => 'mysql',
           'host'      => env('DB_HOST2', 'localhost'),
           'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE2', ''),
           'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME2', ''),
           'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD2', ''),
           'charset'   => 'utf8',
           'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
           'prefix'    => '',
           'strict'    => false,
   ],
   ```
2. В файле `.env` добавить доступы к этому подключению, то есть `DB_HOST2, DB_DATABASE2, DB_USERNAME2, DB_PASSWORD2.`
3. Дальше есть несколько способов, как обращаться к этому подключению. Вот один из них:

   ```
   $users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select("select ...");
   ```